# Find all positive integers $n$ such that $\displaystyle \left({-1 + i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n + \left({-1 - i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n = 2$?

Tags: complex-numbers, binomial-theorem

> Find all positive integers $n$ such that $\displaystyle \left({-1 + i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n + \left({-1 - i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n = 2$ ?

---

I wrote $\displaystyle \left({-1 + i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n + \left({-1 - i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n = 2$ as 
$$2\Re\left(\left({-1 + i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n\right) = 2 \implies \Re\left(\left({-1 + i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n\right) = 1$$

But I don't know how to proceed now. I can't use polar representation of complex numbers. Please provide me some direction.

Comment: **Hint:**  Both $\frac{-1\pm\text{i}\sqrt{3}}{2}$ have unit modulus.  So, the only way this sum can be $2$ is when it comes from $1+1$.

Comment: Ok I get the answer but I don't understand why having unit modulus implies sum from 1 + 1 ? Can you explain the reasoning behind your answer.

Comment: Triangle Inequality...

Comment: No wait I did not get the answer because it is asked for +ve integers and 0 is not a +ve integer.

Comment: $n=0$ is not the only integral answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that $\left| \frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt 3}{2} \right| = 1$, hence this holds for all $n$th powers of these quantities also.

The triangle inequality states that $|a| + |b| \geq |a+b|$, with equality holding if and only if $a$ is a scalar multiple of $b$.

In our case, if we assume that the final condition holds, we have that for $a,b = \left(\frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n$ (it doesn't matter which is which), $2 = |a| + |b| \geq |a+b| = 2$, which means equality is being obtained in the triangle inequality.

This means that $\left(\frac{-1 + i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n$ is a scalar multiple of $\left(\frac{-1 - i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n$. However, since both have modulus $1$, we can check that this happens if and only if $\left(\frac{-1 + i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n = \left(\frac{-1 - i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n$.

Hence, dividing both sides by $\left(\frac{-1 - i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n$ (it can't be zero, as it has modulus $1$), we get that (I leave you to see this) $\left(\frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n = 1$.

If you know your roots of unity well, this gives $n = 3k$, where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: @A---B This is a well-known trick. Do keep it in mind. You are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for this. It will be useful for my upcoming exam.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\dfrac{-1+\sqrt3i}2=e^{i120^\circ}, \dfrac{-1-\sqrt3i}2=e^{-i120^\circ}$

$$2= \left({-1 + i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n + \left({-1 - i\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right)^n=e^{i120^\circ n}+e^{-i120^\circ n}=2\cos(120^\circ n) $$

$$\iff\cos(120^\circ n)=1$$

$$\implies120^\circ n=360^\circ m$$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't use polar form.

Answer (score 1):

When you get stuck on a problem like this, it often helps to simply compute some examples, in hopes you'll spot a pattern in the results.  In this case

$$\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^2=\left(1-2i\sqrt3-3\over4\right)=\left(-2-2i\sqrt3\over4\right)=\left(-1-i\sqrt3\over2\right)$$

so

$$\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^3=\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^2=\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)\left(-1-i\sqrt3\over2\right)
=\left(1+3\over4\right)=1$$

at which point you might well say Wow!  If you don't, just keep going until you do:

$$\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^4=\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^3=\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)\cdot1=\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)$$

$$\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^5=\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^2\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^3=\left(-1-i\sqrt3\over2\right)\cdot1=\left(-1-i\sqrt3\over2\right)$$

$$\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^6=\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^3\left(-1+i\sqrt3\over2\right)^3=1\cdot1=1$$

Once you see the pattern, then you can hope to understand it along the lines of the other answers that have already been posted.

In short, there is no need to wait for a burst of inspiration that solves a problem in one fell swoop; playing with examples is often illuminating, and can pave the way to understanding.  At the very least it gives you something to do while you're puzzling over how to approach the probem.

Comment: I really like the "commentary" over the question. Thanks.